# How do I use dimensions?

Tags: java, swing, dimension, jslider

So I'm trying to resize a JSlider which is in a layout manager. Because of this (or so I have heard) I need to set its preferred size. The setPreferedSize does not accept int, int as I expected, but instead accepts a dimension. My question is, how do I actually set the dimension?

I have tried:

`dimension sliderLength = 500, 10`

```
dimension sliderLength = (500, 10)
```

And I have tried

```
dimension sliderLength(500, 10)
```

All without success.

Comment: So you skipped the basics of Java programming and can't even construct an object? How did you manage to use a JSlider if you don't know even that?

Comment: [Read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 10));
```

or:

```
Dimension sliderLength = new Dimension(500, 10);
slider.setPreferredSize(sliderLength);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 10);
    }
};
```

Comment: That's true, but you broke this [principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html), and you are creating a new dimnesion each time..